# How to close and re-open indexedDB database without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

In attempting to catch errors related to indexedDB database requests and offer options to salvage the database, I'd like to offer the option of closing the database, re-opening it, and resetting the mapping data values held in RAM. Because the page is acted on by an extension, I don't want the user to refresh the browser but to use a button provided in a custom error dialogue.

It seems simple enough but I must be missing something important.  The `close` method doesn't return a promise but [MDN documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/close) state it returns immediately and closes the database in a separate thread.  I tried defining a simple event listener `db.addEventListener( 'close', handler, false )` ( as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/onclose)) before using `db.close()` but it is never invoked.  The database appears to close because, after clicking the button, the rest of the database actions no longer work.  I want to re-open the database after it has closed, because that will trigger a set of initialization steps and attempt a fresh start without reloading the page.

My question is how can I listen for the database `close` event before attempting to open the database again and how can I know if the `close` method failed?

Thank you.

```
function DB_restart() 
  { 
    DB.addEventListener( 'close', expected, false );
    DB.close();

    function expected( evt )
      {
        console.log( 'closed' );
        console.log( evt ); 
        // ... DB_open() ...
       }
} // close DB_restart
```

I didn't notice [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/close_event) information at MDN earlier which states the `close` event doesn't fire when the `close` method is used but only if it is unexpected, which @Josh pointed out in an answer that appears to have been subsequently removed. So, the above will not work.

Perhaps, since in this case, it is known for certain that all transactions have closed, and the `close` is requested before a new `open`, the close will always complete first. A `db.close()` immediately followed by a database open call has been working in this case thus far.

---

After working on this a bit further, it appears that closing the database is unnecessary for my simple case of a restart or reset, at least in Firefox. The objective is to re-initialize the mapping variables just as when the page loads without re-loading the page and that is triggered by the `onsuccess` event of the `IDBFactory.open()`. Attempting to open an already open database appears to still fire the `onsuccess` event rather than error or silently ignore the request.  Since I'm not changing the version, if this is the normal response, there is no need to close.  It does appear that using close immediately before an open works, too, because over the past couple days it has not errored once in testing; but, in this case, it is kown that there are no open transactions for which to wait.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395686): what's actually happening that made you think the solution was to close and reopen the database?

Comment: I'm just trying to set up error catching options in the event something does happen, most of which are specific; but, if those fail, I want to give this as an option in case somehow the mapping data held in RAM is no longer consistent with that in the database.

Comment: Closing and reopening a database does not change the data in that database, so in what you describe, it's a completely noop: it makes no difference whether you just sync back from the DB, or whether you first close it and then reopen it and _then_ sync from the DB. So why close and reopen at all?

Comment: The objective is to not have the program fail, freeze, or display anything constructed from 'bad' data under any circumstances. When there is a data issue, error catching can lead into a dead-end; and error catching, apart from fabricated scenarios is unpredicatable, for all that is known is the block of code from which the error was thrown. This method works right now, at least for fabricated errors. It can correct the issue only if the mapping data in RAM became inconsistent with the database, but it can also get the user out of a dead-end situation and allow for correction afterward.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I have no idea what you're actually trying to do here, because that sounds like a very strange way to deal with data management (your IndexedDB _is_ your client-side, in-RAM data store already, so the solution to "things desyncing" is to use the IndexedDB, not take data out, store it somewhere else, and then end up with a desync because the values in the DB changed) but hopefully someone else looking in on this question has a better idea of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a few points:

- The `"close"` event is only fired on an abnormal close - e.g. the disk was disconnected, unrecoverable corruption was detected, etc. Calling `close()` from script will not fire it.
- When calling `close()` then `open()` (without a version bump), the new connection could open before the previous connection closes if there are transactions running. You are able to observe this by starting a transaction with a loop that makes a new get() request when the previous request succeeds (until a boolean variable is set to true), leave that running, then open a new connection, and only stop the loop (by setting the boolean to true) after the open succeeds.

Overall, it's not clear what you're asking though. If you determine that the data in the database itself is bad you probably want to close() and issue a `deleteDatabase()` call, and ensure that all your connections do a `close()` in response to a `"versionchange"` event so that the delete isn't blocked. Once the delete succeeds, you could reconstruct/repopulate the database.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I understand your two bullets. In my particular case I will know for certain that there re no open transactions.  The data is added by the user as the user 'builds' in the extension, such that th edatabse cannot be deleted and reloaded because the data exists only on the client at that time.  Thus, the purpose is to 'reset' some mapping fields in RAM and in the databse in attempt to correct certain types of errors, such as looking for a ket that no longer exists because a delete operation failed in such a way as to delete the record but not update the mapping data.

Comment: It all depends upon where an error takes place.  I try to handle rollbacks to avoid all of these issues but just in case I miss something or there is a power failure, I want to procide a means of salvaging the database.  It may sound odd without all of the information but error handling I find to be quite difficult especially when it involves data and mappings.  Nonetheless, what I stated in my questions works. No need to close; attempting to open an alread open databse does not error and fires the onsuccess event again.